# php using $_get command to get foreign key

Tags: php

The users are registered in the db. When I submit from inputting the necessary info on the web, it would refresh and won't store the data in the db. I think there is something wrong with the $_get command. I'm trying to receive the id that is a foreign key of that table and store the data into the db.

```
<? include_once 'session.php';
include_once 'newtryconn.php';
include_once 'utilities.php';

if(isset($_POST['preferences'])){
    $religion = $_POST['religion'];
    $home = $_POST['home'];
    $occuption = $_POST['occuption'];
    $roommates = $_POST['roommates'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $id = $_GET['id'];

        $sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO preferences (religion, home, occuption, roommates, phone, id)
        VALUES (:religion, :home, :occuption, :roommates, :phone, :id)";

            //use PDO prepared to sanitize data
        $statement = $db->prepare($sqlInsert);

        //add the data into the database
        $statement->execute(array(':religion' => $religion, ':home' => $home, ':occuption' => $occuption, ':roommates' => $roommates, ':phone' => $phone, ':id' => $id));
        header("location: homepage.php");
}
}  


?>
```

Comment: **POST** and **GET** don't ordinarily go together. If your form was **POST**ed look for the id in `$_POST`

Comment: Its not a good idea to pass id in the $_GET but if so it can be done when you put `http://yourhost/script?id=yourId` such an url in the `action` attribute of post form

Comment: @HankyPanky If OP has the user id in his action attribute then this is [plausible](http://www.darkbee.be/stack/post.php?t=1487748996)

Comment: That's why I said ordinarily

Comment: Anyway, @kluless you should check if the SQL statement did not throw any errors, which is not the case in the current code. You just reroute the user..

Comment: Do you mean a separate if(isset) for GET, not within Post? Users are assigned the ID when they register, I have started a session(), because I make  sign in before they can go to this page. I'm trying to refer that id, which is a foreign key within this table, so im trying to use GET to get their id so the POST data goes into the right id.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of GET.

Comment: I used $_session instead of GET and got the ID of the user when I echoed it.